# How to get the webport address of node in Corda?

Tags: corda

How to get the running port address of a node declared in the `NodeDriver.kt` file like shown below:

```
startWebserver(startNode(
    providedName = CordaX500Name("Common-name", "Organization", "Locality", "CN"),
    rpcUsers = listOf(user)).getOrThrow())
```

Same way how to get the port address which we declared in the `build.gradle` (while running through terminal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the node driver, you get the address of the node's webserver using:

```
val webserverHandle = startWebserver(partyAHandle).getOrThrow()
val webserverAddress = webserverHandle.listenAddress
```

When running the node via the terminal:

- In Corda 3.1, you'd be able to retrieve the webserver address by parsing the `node.conf` file to retrieve the `webAddress` property
- In Corda 4+, the `webAddress` property will be removed from the `node.conf` file. You'll have to pass the webserver address as a configuration property

Comment: What if I want to get this in the API file?

Comment: There is no built-in API to achieve this.

Comment: So what I will do if I want to return all the nodes and corresponding port address in an api call?

Comment: Hmm, wait. Do you want the webserver ports or the P2P ports?

Comment: web port,which we used to load the corresponding pages of each node

Comment: node {
name "CN=Wholesaler,O=Home,L=10022,C=GB"
p2pPort 10020
rpcSettings {
address("localhost:10021")
adminAddress("localhost:10061")
}
**webPort 10022**
cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}

Comment: Yes, this isn't possible currently unless you pass in a configuration property.

Comment: is it possible to edit the configuration property in Corda3.1

Comment: No, this is something you'd have to set up yourself.